# Сохранение txt файла с стилем и размером текста в Java

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

В JTextArea можно указать цвет шрифта, стиль, размер. Если сохранить txt файл, указав размер и стиль и открыв файл после перезапуска программы, то все будет как обычно. Как сделать так что-бы при открытии файла ставился тот-же стиль, размер и шрифт который указывался при сохранении? Спасибо.

Код сохранения файла как:

```
BufferedWriter bwriter;
        JFileChooser savefile = new JFileChooser();
        int saveas = savefile.showSaveDialog(null);
        if (saveas == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            try {
                bwriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(savefile.getSelectedFile()));
                jta.write(bwriter);
                bwriter.close();
                open2(savefile.getSelectedFile());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File saved.");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The file cannot be saved");

            }

        }
```

Код сохранения файла:

```
 if (openedfile == null) {
            BufferedWriter bwriter;
            String nameoffile = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write name for this file. Example:filename.txt");
            savefile.setSelectedFile(new File(nameoffile));
            int save = savefile.showSaveDialog(null);
            if (save == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                try {
                    bwriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(savefile.getSelectedFile()));
                    jta.write(bwriter);
                    bwriter.close();
                    open2(savefile.getSelectedFile());
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File saved.");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The file cannot be saved");

                }

            }
        } else if (openedfile != null) {
            try {
                BufferedWriter bwriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(openedfile));
                jta.write(bwriter);
                bwriter.close();
                needsave = false;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File saved.");
                filename = openedfile;
                win.setTitle("Saved -" + filename + "- SimpleTextMaster 0.8(Beta)");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The file cannot be saved");


            }
        }
```

Код открытия:

```
if (needsave == true) {
            int input = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to save the current file?\"");
            if (input == 0) {
                BufferedWriter bwriter;
                String nameoffile = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write name for this file. Example:filename.txt");
                JFileChooser savefile = new JFileChooser();
                savefile.setSelectedFile(new File(nameoffile));
                int save = savefile.showSaveDialog(null);
                if (save == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    try {
                        bwriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(savefile.getSelectedFile()));
                        jta.write(bwriter);
                        bwriter.close();
                        needsave = false;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File saved.");
                        JFileChooser openfile = new JFileChooser();
                        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Txt file", "txt");
                        openfile.setFileFilter(filter);
                        int open = openfile.showDialog(null, "Open file");
                        if (open == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                            try {
                                filename = openfile.getSelectedFile();
                                openedfile = openfile.getSelectedFile();
                                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(openfile.getSelectedFile()));
                                String ln;
                                jta.setText(null);
                                while ((ln = br.readLine()) != null) {
                                    jta.append(ln + "\n");
                                }
                                br.close();
                                win.setTitle(filename + " - SimpleTextMaster 0.8(Beta)");
                                needsave = false;
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File opened.");
                            } catch (IOException e1) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The file cannot be opened");
                            }

                        }
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The file cannot be saved");

                    }
                }
            } else if (input == 1) {
                JFileChooser openfile = new JFileChooser();
                FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Txt file", "txt");
                openfile.setFileFilter(filter);
                int open = openfile.showDialog(null, "Open file");
                if (open == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    try {
                        filename = openfile.getSelectedFile();
                        openedfile = openfile.getSelectedFile();
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(openfile.getSelectedFile()));
                        String ln;
                        jta.setText(null);
                        while ((ln = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            jta.append(ln + "\n");
                        }
                        br.close();
                        win.setTitle(filename + " - SimpleTextMaster 0.8(Beta)");
                        needsave = false;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File opened.");
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The file cannot be opened");
                    }

                }
            } else if (input == 2) {
                return;
            }

        } else if (needsave == false) {
            JFileChooser openfile = new JFileChooser();
            FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Txt file", "txt");
            openfile.setFileFilter(filter);
            int open = openfile.showDialog(null, "Open file");
            if (open == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                try {
                    filename = openfile.getSelectedFile();
                    openedfile = openfile.getSelectedFile();
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(openfile.getSelectedFile()));
                    String ln;
                    jta.setText(null);
                    while ((ln = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        jta.append(ln + "\n");
                    }
                    br.close();
                    win.setTitle(filename + " - SimpleTextMaster 0.8(Beta)");
                    needsave = false;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File opened.");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The file cannot be opened");
                }

            }


        }
```

Извиняюсь если вы найдёте плохой код, я новичок.

Comment: можно пожалуйста код сохранения и загрузки (я постараюсь добавить туда то, чего вы хотите)

Comment: Agzam4, добавил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Не дублируйте код, сделайте методы: `save(File f)`, и метод `save_as()`("сохранить как"), который будет вызывать метод `save(File f)`
2. `txt` файл хранит только текст, потому, если Вы хотите сохранять данные шрифта Вам следует преобразовать их в текст и сохранить вместе с текстом из `JTextArea`
3. Я заменил код сохранения и чтения

Вот методы:

```
private void open(String path) {
        try {
            byte[] all;
            all = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
            filename = path; // Обновляем имя открытого файла
            String str = new String(all);
            String datastr = str.split("\n")[0];
            String data[] = datastr.split("\t");
            System.out.println(datastr);
            jtextArea.setFont(new Font(data[0], Integer.valueOf(data[1]), Integer.valueOf(data[2])));
            jtextArea.setText(str.substring(datastr.length()+1));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    private void save() {
        save_as(new File(filename)); // filename - это имя открытого файла
    }
    
    private void save_as(File file) {
        String saveText = jtextArea.getFont().getFamily() + "\t" // Имя шрифта
                + jtextArea.getFont().getStyle() + "\t" // Стиль шрифта
                + jtextArea.getFont().getSize() + "\n" // Размер шрифта
                + jtextArea.getText(); // Текст
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file)) {
            writer.write(saveText);
            writer.flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Вот пример использования:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class JFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    
    String filename = "test";
    JTextArea jtextArea;
    
    public JFrame() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(file);
        
        JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Open");
        file.add(open);
        
        JMenuItem save = new JMenuItem("Save");
        file.add(save);
        
        JMenuItem save_as = new JMenuItem("Save as");
        file.add(save_as);
        
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        
        jtextArea = new JTextArea();
        String fonts[] = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames(); // Шрифты
        // Устанавлиеваем случайный шрифт для jtextArea
        jtextArea.setFont(new Font(fonts[(int) (Math.random()*fonts.length)], (int) (Math.random()*2), 10 + (int) (Math.random()*10)));
        contentPane.add(jtextArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        save.addActionListener(e -> save());
        save_as.addActionListener(e -> {
            JFileChooser savefile = new JFileChooser();
            if (savefile.showSaveDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                save_as(savefile.getSelectedFile());
            }
        });
        open.addActionListener(e -> {
             JFileChooser savefile = new JFileChooser();
                if (savefile.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    open(savefile.getSelectedFile().toString());
                }
        });
    }

    private void open(String path) {
        try {
            byte[] all;
            all = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
            filename = path;
            String str = new String(all);
            String datastr = str.split("\n")[0];
            String data[] = datastr.split("\t");
            System.out.println(datastr);
            jtextArea.setFont(new Font(data[0], Integer.valueOf(data[1]), Integer.valueOf(data[2])));
            jtextArea.setText(str.substring(datastr.length()+1));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    private void save() {
        save_as(new File(filename));
    }
    
    private void save_as(File file) {
        String saveText = jtextArea.getFont().getFamily() + "\t" // Имя шрифта
                + jtextArea.getFont().getStyle() + "\t" // Стиль шрифта
                + jtextArea.getFont().getSize() + "\n" // Размер шрифта
                + jtextArea.getText(); // Текст
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file)) {
            writer.write(saveText);
            writer.flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, я вам очень благодарен.